# Sharing current screenshot of the device via ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

In android, is it possible to share the current screenshot of the device via ACTION_SEND intent?

Comment: Yes it is possible. https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html (Your question is not very precise.)

Comment: @user1615898 Did my answer work?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a screenshot and send it with intent like below:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intentToAdd.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

I assumed that you know how to take a screenshot....let me know if you had other questions about it.